# Is there a way to tell if an email has an OneDrive attachment?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am querying ews using the getitem method. I don't see any field uri [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494315(v=exchg.150).aspx) that tells me if the email has a OneDrive/SharePoint attachment.
The "Attachments" field does not give me this information; that field only works with genuine email attachments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you set the RequestedServerVersion to Exchange 2016 and then when you do a GetItem any OneDrive Attachments will be returned as ReferanceAttachments https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt759538(v=exchg.150).aspx where the AttachLongPathName is the URL to use to get the file. (if you haven't set the RequestedServerVersion correctly then these attachment will just be returned as normal fileattachments).